# Comic book from the '50s-'60s about an alien who likes to smoke cigarettes

Tags: story-identification, comics, aliens

My grandpa was talking about a comic book he loved from when he was a kid. He said it was about an alien who came to Earth and learned about smoking cigarettes. When he got back to his home planet -- which was made of gas -- he went to light a cigarette, and the planet blew up from the flame. The book was from the early '60s. Does anyone know the name?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: This reminds me a little of Hal Clement's *Iceworld*. In that novel the combustion products of cigarettes were intoxicating and addictive to beings from another world (who breathed gaseous sulfur). But this was not a comic, and no planet blew up. So not a match,